# Dart_NewString expects argument 'str' to be valid UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, dart

I just begin to use Dart, and I'm wondering why my first app doesn't work.

```
void main() {  print("Hello, World!");}
```

When I run the app, I get this error message:

> dart --enable-checked-mode HelloWorld.dart
>
> Dart_NewString expects argument 'str' to be valid UTF-8.

I'm new, I follow the tutorial on the website http://www.dartlang.org/docs/editor/getting-started/#code And Hello World doesn't work -_-

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the file is not encoded in UTF-8.

Try changing the file encoding to UTF-8 and retry.

Comment: Actually, I dont see how to push the UTF-8 encoding. The Hello World program is taken on the tutorial and they (dart-staff) don't write it.. I think i miss understood something..

Comment: What editor are you using? I remember downloading a source file from Dropbox and it wasn't UTF-8 encoded so running the file caused this very same problem. Create a new file with Dart Editor manually and write the code manually, it must work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:html';

num rotatePos = 0;

void main() {
  query("#text")
    ..text = "Click me!"
    ..on.click.add(rotateText);
}

void rotateText(Event event) {
  rotatePos += 360;
  query("#text").style
    ..transition = "1s"
    ..transform = "rotate(${rotatePos}deg)";
}
```